# Disable jsviews datepicker depending on another value

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, jsrender, jsviews

I need to disable a datepicker depending on the value of another property in the model.

How can I achieve this?

I know i can disable it by setting _disabled=true|false but can I also include conditional expression and what is the syntax. I need to be able to react to the changes in the other property and have the date picker update disable state accordingly. The other property is a data linked select with numeric values.

Something like

```
{^{datepicker 
  _disabled="{:OtherProperty > 1}}
  DatePickerValue
  dataFormat="mm/dd/yy"
  dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
{{/datepicker}}"
```

Is this possible and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

You can put an expression directly as a value of a tag property: `_disabled=OtherProperty > 1` - which will initialize the value.

But by default, tag properties are not data-linked for dynamic changes. You have to opt in to that by prepending a `^`. See *[Binding to named properties of tags](https://www.jsviews.com/#linked-tag-syntax@linkedproperties)*, and also the section ***Data-linked option*** [here](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jqui/api)

See for example the dynamic binding of `^_numberOfMonths=...` in the [Datepicker variants](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jqui/datepicker/variants) sample.

So in your case you need something like:

```
{^{datepicker 
  ^_disabled=OtherProperty>1
  DatePickerValue
  dataFormat="mm/dd/yy"
  dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" /}}
```